# How to update isis project core

Tags: java, apache, maven, intellij-idea, isis

I'm just getting started with apache isis, and I've had some good runs. However I've come across an issue with wicket which has been fixed in wicket v7.6 (isis v1.15). I'm on isis v1.14

I'm having serious troubles updating the dependencies.

I'm at the stage (in IntelliJ) of ** Module Settings > Dependencies **, and just manually editing the references, (and it's causing a lot of issues)

Is there an easy way to update isis that I'm missing or is it meant to this hard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the Wicket dependencies in your pom.xml. This will override the dependencies Isis brings with it. This is a standard Maven behavior.

Comment: The pom.xml in the root of isis? I now get enforcer errors on compile

Comment: isis-viewer-wicket-applib is no longer compatible with wicket, and updating isis-viewer-wicket-applib to 1.15 has caused lots of type errors

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "no longer compatible with Wicket". But you should not change the version of Isis modules, like isis-viewer-wicket-applib! I said you should "add the Wicket dependencies in your pom.xml", i.e. add `wicket-util`, `wicket-request`, `wicket-core`, ... in your application's pom.xml